# says my heroku toolbelt was installed, but i cant find the programs

Tags: macos, heroku

I've installed heroku tool belt about 5 times now and I can't find anything relating to installing it on my computer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You realise they are command line programs and do not have a GUI or appear in your Applications folder?

Comment: So how do I work it? I'm new to the whole idea of this. So I'm trying to get started. How do I work them?

Comment: For Windows GUI version, the folder is C:\Program Files\Heroku

Answer (score 3):

Open Terminal and at the prompt type;

```
which heroku
```

You should see something like

```
/usr/bin/heroku
```

This will tell you if the program is installed.

To get some help from the program type

```
heroku help
```

From here on in you're on your own but I would suggest getting comfortable with the command line and what each of the tools does by referring to the documentation and guides on Heroku's Dev Center. https://devcenter.heroku.com/

Comment: I opened terminal. I was in the middle of typing "which heroku" and all this crap popped up. What do I do? It's not letting me delete anything.

Comment: "all this crap" doesn't tell me much. Nothing should "pop up" until you hit return. I'd suggest that perhaps you might need to get a bit more familiar with the command line and these kind of tools and development before trying to get to grips with Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `heroku` command from your terminal.

Just write `heroku login` to your terminal, and enter your credentials.

For further information : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#set-up